# How do I add a new property to a prop in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component `listBooks` which is being passed a prop, `bookShelf`.  The `bookShelf` prop is an array of objects.  Each object has properties such as `title`, `author`, `pageCount`.

I would like to add a Shelf property to each of the objects.  I've tried:

```
this.props.bookShelf.prototype.shelf = "";
```

This gives me an error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'shelf' of undefined.` I've also tried this variant:

```
let bookShelf = this.props.bookShelf;
  bookShelf.prototype.shelf = "none";
```

The array is being populated by objects from an API call.

```
componentDidMount(){
  BooksAPI.getAll().then((bookShelf)=> {
    this.setState({ bookShelf : bookShelf })
    console.log(bookShelf)

  })
```

I also tried placing the lines above in this function to no avail.

Guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `this.props.bookShelf.shelf = "";`

Answer (score 1):

> The 'bookShelf' prop is an array of objects. Each object has
>   properties such as title, author, pageCount.
>
> I would like to add a Shelf property to each of the objects.

I'm not whether you want to do it dynamically at some point but you can do it when you set them in a state with `map`:

```
componentDidMount(){
  BooksAPI.getAll().then((bookShelf)=> {
    bookShelf.forEach(b => {
      b.shelf = "";
    })
    this.setState({ bookShelf })

  })
```

Comment: This worked, but I had to replace === with = bookShelf.forEach(b => {
      b.shelf = "";
    })

Answer (score 0):

Just loop the array of objects and assign the property:

```
this.props.bookShelf.map(book => book.shelf = "none");
```